# using StringTokenizer.countTokens() in for condition

Tags: java

Code 1:

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        StringTokenizer s1 = new StringTokenizer("as df gg hj kl");
        System.out.println(s1.countTokens());
        int a = s1.countTokens();
        for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){
            System.out.print(i + "\t");
            System.out.println(s1.nextToken());
        }
    }
}
```

Output of Code 1:

```
5
0   as
1   df
2   gg
3   hj
4   kl
```

Code 2:

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        StringTokenizer s1 = new StringTokenizer("as df gg hj kl");
        System.out.println(s1.countTokens());
        for(int i = 0; i < s1.countTokens(); i++){
            System.out.print(i + "\t");
            System.out.println(s1.nextToken());
        }
    }
}
```

Output for Code 2:

```
5
0   as
1   df
2   gg
```

- Why for the second code I am getting partial output?
- Is it due to the `nextToken()` method advancing the position in each iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, the [StringTokenizer.countTokens](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#countTokens())() is not a constant value instead it returns the number of times that this tokenizer's nextToken method can be called before it generates
an exception.
Quote:

> Calculates the number of times that this tokenizer's nextToken method can be called before it generates an exception. The current position is not advanced.

so every time you call `s1.nextToken()` the `s1.countTokens()` in returning another value, (is getting shorter and shorter) somewhere are both values getting crossed, (int i in the for loop and the `countTokens`) which is unexpectedly bringing you out of the for loop

Comment: I agree to your point.. But still i m unable to guess why i m getting partial output for the Code 2

Comment: Ive Updated the answer, the i is increasing and s1.countTokens is getting smaller, so at  some point the condition i<s1.countTokens is not met anymore

Answer (score 0):

Don't evaluate same results all the time in the for loop. So before for loop you can introduce new variable call count and assign s1.countTokens(); to that and use the count variable instead s1.countTokens();